# Why are the Alolan trial captains so young?

Tags: pokemon

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Trial_Captain), the trial captains in the region of Alola, whom the player must defeat on their island challenge, are all between 11 and 19. By contrast, their equivalents in most other regions, the gym leaders, are of varying ages, with most being adults and some being quite old.

Of course, the player character is always a kid, but the conceit is that they're particularly talented, and most people don't get as far as they do as early as they do, thus why the Champions tend to be a bit older, as are of course the gym leaders and Elite Four.

Why are the Alolan trial captains particularly young?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Because people over 20 can't be Trial Captains

Mallow tells the player this in the Generation 7 games.

[image: Gen 7]

Which explains why the trial captains are all between 11-19. Not too young that they cannot conduct a trial, and not too old that they are not allowed to be a captain.

---

Notes:

I got that image [off a Google search](https://knowyourmeme.com/photos/1193442-pokemon-sun-and-moon) of "20 years trial captain", but I can vouch (as one who has played the games) that Mallow does say this whilst the player is in Lush Jungle.

Comment: OK, but going beyond that, is there any reason for this vs. the other system?

Comment: @Adamant Sadly I can't find any more information about this. Perhaps it's a tradition in Alola where the young and talented are given the opportunity to host a trial. To make sure 1 person doesn't remain as a trial captain indefinitely.